# Database hardening

Tags: sql-server-2008

How we can harden sql server 2008?
Is there any detailed article on hardening of sql server 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/wp-sql-2008-security.aspx)

It's a basic MS white paper.
There is a lot on the web, just google it!